# Install package without some dependencies

Tags: apt, dpkg, mysql, cacti

We want to install a package, here cacti, without pulling some dependencies, here the MySQL Server.

It is possible to do it using, apt, apt-get (or aptitude) ?

We already have a remote MySQL server and we don't want to install a new server locally that would not be used, nor running.

Maybe some solutions would exist with dpkg ?

Goal is to keep the update path of apt (apt update) to keep cacti up-to-date.

Best Regards.

Comment: There is no way to avoid dependencies unless you change the deb package.

Answer (score 2):

In fact, looking at package details located at https://packages.ubuntu.com/eoan/cacti, the database is an *recommended* dependency.

So installing with flag **--no-install-recommends** will avoid the MySQL Server being pulled as dependency like

```
apt install cacti cacti-spine --no-install-recommends
```

Comment: It doesn't seem that recommends are installed by default.

Comment: *Recommends* seems to be installed by default. That's not the case for *suggested* packages